Docker ERROR: failed to solve: Canceled: context canceled
When trying to build my docker image i get ERROR: failed to solve: Canceled: context canceled
This is happening when i run docker build --tag sm:sm . Ps im on windows 11

Tried docker rollback version.
Tried SET DOCKER_BUILDKIT=0 and SET COMPOSE_DOCKER_CLI_BUILD=0

And this is my Dockerfile
# FROM selects the image to find on docker hub and selects the tag specified. Here we select the python image and the 3.8 version (as tag)
FROM python:3.8
# this is the work directory
WORKDIR /app
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt install -y libgl1-mesa-glx
# Copy the requirements.txt
COPY requirements.txt /app
# Run the pip - install
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
# Expose the port that the container will communicate
EXPOSE 5000
# Copy source code and everything
COPY . /user/src/app
CMD [ "python", "app.py" ]

What i get:
[+] Building 5.2s (6/12)                                                                                       docker:default
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                     0.1s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 553B                                                                                     0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                        0.1s
 => => transferring context: 45B                                                                                         0.1s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/python:3.8                                                            3.8s
 => [auth] library/python:pull token for registry-1.docker.io                                                            0.0s
 => CANCELED [internal] load build context                                                                               1.0s
 => => transferring context: 2.40MB                                                                                      1.0s
 => CANCELED [1/7] FROM docker.io/library/python:3.8@sha256:6ea16099cac9f66419d1fc3a63aaa9d783214e8e38d2a1c0db2bfb085  1.1s
 => => resolve docker.io/library/python:3.8@sha256:6ea16099cac9f66419d1fc3a63aaa9d783214e8e38d2a1c0db2bfb0852ef9b7     0.1s
 => => sha256:3b74f020507cc447d399db5c64cae14579323514dcc2c1d4fb2256fdfd304b 2.01kB / 2.01kB                           0.0s
 => => sha256:6ea16099cac9f66419d1fc3a63aaa9d783214e8e38d2a1c0db2bfb0852ef9b 1.86kB / 1.86kB                           0.0s
 => => sha256:17b8b8dc7004de4f94b101a88b71bffd77132e07fd5ff3a59299c6333d2bf7 7.36kB / 7.36kB                           0.0s
 => => sha256:1468e7ff95fcb865fbc4dee7094f8b99c4dcddd6eb2180cf044c7396baf6fc 2.10MB / 49.58MB                          1.0s
 => => sha256:c4c40c3e3cdf945721f480e1d939aac857876fdb5c33b8fbfcf655c63b0b94 0B / 64.14MB                              1.0s
 => => sha256:2cf9c2b42f41b1845f3e4421b723d56146db82939dc884555e077768e18132 1.05MB / 24.05MB                          1.0s
ERROR: failed to solve: Canceled: context canceled

